# Adding a auto generated id to record in the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add an auto generated auto-increment id to a query results. 
For example, for the query

```
SELECT TOP 3 Users.Reputation FROM Users ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Instead of getting

- 101
- 100
- 99

I want to get

- 1, 101
- 2, 100
- 3, 99

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm working on the Data Explorer, so regular MS SQL I'm guessing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC),
    Users.Reputation
 FROM
    Users
)
SELECT TOP 3
    RowNum, Reputation
FROM
    CTE
ORDER BY  
    RowNum
```

This is a CTE (Common Table Expression) available in SQL Server **2005** and newer, combined with the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function, also available in 2005 and newer.

It creates an "on-the-fly" view for just the next statement and allows to do some extra processing first, before selecting. The `ROW_NUMBER()` just adds a consecutive number to each row in the order defined in the `OVER (ORDER BY ....)` clause. So the first row gets #1, the second #2 and so on.

Read more about CTE's here: [MSDN - Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Read more about `ROW_NUMBER` and other ranking functions here: [MSDN ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: could you explain a bit more about this solution?

Comment: Curious to know if this is > MSSQL 2005 solution or works always?

Comment: @Vikdor: works on most modern DBMS (although other DBMS need the statement terminator at the end not at the beginning).

Comment: Is it a bit overkill, or not? A simple select could do that with only an OVER(Oder BY...) clause.)

Comment: @AndrásOttó: try adding an `ORDER BY` by that row number to your solution! :-) I find it easier to wrap everything into a CTE and then be able to use the columns defined by the CTE **by name**

Comment: Yes I see your point, but he needed the same column as order by, so... :)
BTW I agree with CTE, usually I'm using it because of readability and recursion. It is great there

Comment: I just tried it, and it is chaning the order in my case. DESC From Max to up and with ASC from MIN to down. (I tried it on a simply int field in a sample database)

Comment: @AndrásOttó: Yes, I saw the same effect in Data Explorer - but as far as I know, the `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER()` clause does not apply to the ordering of the resultset, really - it's just used to determine the sequential numbering. But I can't find any clear documentation on this topic right now. My advice: just don't rely on it - if you need order in the result set - specify it.

Comment: But it is a good hint, and I will try to find any documentation about it, because I just used it in the past.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way if it is an SQL Server, then this one:

```
SELECT TOP 3 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Users.Reputation DESC), 
Users.Reputation 
FROM Users
```

Update:

I checked the Query Execution plan, and the inner order by, which defines the logical order of the rows within each partition of the result set (I did not use a specified partitioning condition in this case) using a Sort step, which is the same as by a normal sort:

```
SELECT Users.Reputation
FROM Users
ORDER BY Users.Reputation DESC
```

After this step there are two intresting step: Segment and Sequence Project. The second one is telling that it is compution over an *ordered* dataset. 
The last steps are a TOP and a SELECT.

I'm intrested in the drawbacks, but it seems OK.

And just a note at the end: with a normal OrderBy with TOP:

```
 SELECT TOP 3 Users.Reputation
    FROM Users
    ORDER BY Users.Reputation DESC
```

The sorting is easier, but almost a same : Sort (Top N sort)